# Compile OpenCV for Python wit contrib modules on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I want to install OpenCV 3 with contrib modules on windows 10 and use it with Python 2.7 (32 bits). I think that the only way to have contrib modules in opencv is compiling it. (not installing with *.exe).

I have compiled OpenCV with contrib modules without problems. I have used Visual Studio 2013, compiling in release mode (for Win32).

After compile OpenCV, I can see the "cv2.pyd" module in `$PYTHON_HOME/Libs/site-packages`

### The problem:

When I try to `import cv2` in Python IDLE I have this error:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

As you can see, I have a 32 bits Python. Also, the module is "detected".

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I had to add the OpenCV *.dll to PATH environment variable. This *.dll are in

```
$OPENCV_HOME/bin/release
```