# Build and Compile OpenCV with Python and GPU Support on Windows 10 VS2015

Tags: python, windows, opencv, cmake

As the question title states, I am trying to compile my own binaries for the Python3 OpenCV library on Windows 10, with CUDA support and the contrib files.

I have been following [this guide](http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/) on installing OpenCV 3 on Windows concurrently with [this one](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/11/compiling-opencv-with-cuda-support/) for compiling OpenCV with CUDA support. This question is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423059/compile-opencv-for-python-wit-contrib-modules-on-windows-10-using-visual-studio), but I am using VS2015, and the solution posted has not solved my issue.

**The Problem**

I was able to successfully follow these guides and configure, generate, and build with CMake (with GUI). However, when I ran Python from a fresh terminal after this, I had the same problem mentioned in the other question I linked previously. I have attempted setting path variables as per this solution, but the problem remained. That is when I noticed this line in my CMake output:

[image: Troubling CMake feedback]

It appears as though CMake is failing to find Python libraries, despite having set them manually as per step 5.2 of the install guide:

[image: Manually-Added Python Locations]

I don't understand how CMake works very much, and I am now at a loss as to how to fix this. Other stackoverflow questions about installing OpenCV are all about a different version, a different OS, or non-GPU-supported.

**The Question**

How can I get CMake to properly install OpenCV with CUDA support such that my Python3 interpreter will run it?

**Relevant Information**

- System: Windows 10 Pro (64 bit)
- CUDA Toolkit Version: 9.1
- Python Version: 3.6.1 (Anaconda 4.4.0 64 bit)
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
- CMake version: 3.10.2
- Visual Studio Version: 14 (VS2015 Win64)

Here's the entire output of CMake:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
at: C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
found Intel IPP IW sources: 2017.0.3
at: C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win
CUDA detected: 9.1
CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-D_FORCE_INLINES
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find Matlab (missing: MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
Looking for tiny_dnn.h
Looking for tiny_dnn.h - found
Found tiny-dnn in: C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/3rdparty/tinydnn/tiny-dnn-1.0.0a3
The protocol buffer compiler is not found (PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE='')
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
Excluding from source files list: C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/modules/imgproc/accum.neon.cpp
Torch importer has been enabled. To run the tests you have to install Torch ('th' executable should be available) and generate testdata using opencv_extra/testdata/dnn/generate_torch_models.py script.
Tesseract:   NO
DNN_FACE_DETECTOR: Download: res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel
Pylint: registered 110 targets. Build 'check_pylint' target to run checks ("cmake --build . --target check_pylint" or "make check_pylint")

General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/opencv_3.0/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-02-02T20:23:50Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.16299 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.10.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2
      SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (2 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (8 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24215.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP12  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP12  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP12  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP12  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          cudart.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.1/lib/x64
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml objdetect phase_unwrapping plot reg surface_matching video xphoto bgsegm cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping dnn face fuzzy img_hash imgcodecs photo shape videoio xobjdetect cudacodec highgui ts bioinspired dpm features2d line_descriptor text calib3d ccalib cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo datasets rgbd stereo structured_light superres tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching
    Disabled:                    js world contrib_world saliency
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 python3 viz cnn_3dobj cvv dnn_modern freetype hdf matlab sfm

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.89.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.71.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.58.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.6.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.5.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO
    Intel Media SDK:             NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use Intel IPP:               2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
               at:               C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
    Use Intel IPP IW:            sources (2017.0.3)
                  at:            C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 9.1)
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  YES
    USE NVCUVID:                 YES
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             30 35 37 50 52 60 61 70
    NVIDIA PTX archs:
    Use fast math:               YES

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/python.exe (ver 3.6.1)

  Python (for build):            C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/python.exe
    Pylint:                      C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/Scripts/pylint.exe (ver: 1.6.4, checks: 110)

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              C:/opencv_3.0/opencv-3.3.1/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the guide correctly, this error wouldn't show up. Sometimes the windows registry entries may not be set correctly. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759845/9329318) is a useful one to check if your registry entries are set correctly.

After changing the registry entries, delete all the cmake files in the opencv directory, restart the cmake GUI and follow the guide again. You can also use [this guide](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/buildcompile-opencv-v3-3-on-windows-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/), that's what I used.